# Mura CMS - Displaying a Class Extension File

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I've created a class extension which allows uploading of an additional file (an image).  The attribute name is "headingFile".

I now need to be get the URL for that image so I can display it.

I've been able to get information about the file with: `$.getBean("fileManager").readMeta($.content('headingFile'))` but can't find how I can get it's URL.

How do I get the URL for a file that has been uploaded with Class extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$.getURLForImage(fileid=$.content('headingFile'),size='large')
```

or

```
$.getURLForImage(fileid=$.content('headingFile'),width=600,height=300)
```

Or if it's not an image and you just want to download it

```
$.getURLForFile(fileid=$.content('headingFile'),method='inline')
```

or

```
$.getURLForFile(fileid=$.content('headingFile'),method='attachment')
```